# UIElement can't be changed inside different name space

Tags: c#, wpf, uielement

EDIT: For new programmers to OOP just calling the class isn't enough if the syntax is looking for a specific variable type it will throw an error. This was the problem as pointed at the answers bellow, this line of code:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetLeft(Gate_list[Gate_list.Count - 1], Pos.X);
```

It has one fatal mistake and that is that the `Canvas.SetLeft` is looking for a canvas child class (in this case a rectangle) and a point. However I sent in a Class type `Gate_list[Gate_list.Count - 1]` when it should've been `Gate_list[Gate_list.Count - 1].GetRect()`

End of edit

I have a delegate that is calling a class in a method. The delegate is detecting a mouse down event on a `Rectangle`([Here is how it's done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863594/trying-to-inherit-mainwindow-into-subclass-but-get-system-stackoverflow)). In the method I'm trying to `SetLeft` on a `Rectangle` I just added to the `Canvas` but get the error CS1503.

I've tried converting it to `System.Windows.UIElement` but System can't be converted.

```cs
public partial class Program
{
    public void Rect_Button_MouseDown(MainWindow MainWind, string Tag)
    {
        Point Pos = new Point();
        Pos = System.Windows.Input.Mouse.GetPosition(MainWind.Main_Canvas);
        if (Drag == false)
        {
            Drag = true;
            Gate_list.Add(new Gate_Class(Convert.ToInt32(Tag),new Rectangle()));
            MainWind.Main_Canvas.Children.Add(Gate_list[Gate_list.Count-1].Get_Rect());
            System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetLeft(Gate_list[Gate_list.Count - 1], Pos.X);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe there should be an away to transfer system.windows but I don't know.

My question comes down to finding a way to convert `Gate_list[]` to `UIElement`.

Comment: You should show us how Gate_Class is, because *THAT* is supposed to be UIElement compatible (from what your code indicates).

Comment: As a note, it is useless to initialize a local variable with a default value directly before assigning a new value to it. Just write `Point Pos = System.Windows.Input.Mouse.GetPosition(MainWind.Main_Canvas);`

Comment: I forgot to add the method in the class Gate_Class to get the rectangle. I was being an idiot and forget the simple sets and tried to make it more complex sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gate_Class` is apparently not a `UIElement`. It should have a `Rectangle` property that returns the `Rectangle` that you pass to its constructor. You can then set the `Canvas.Left` property of the `Rectangle`:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetLeft(Gate_list[Gate_list.Count - 1].Rectangle, Pos.X);
```

---

```
public class Gate_Class
{
    public Gate_Class(int tag, Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        //...
        Rectangle = rectangle;
    }

    public Rectangle Rectangle { get; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add .rectangle at the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think in last line of your code you are providing `Gate_list[Gate_list.Count - 1]` but this is your custom class and not the `Rectangle` you just created. I can deduce from your code that you can get the `Rectangle` by using `Gate_list[Gate_list.Count - 1].Get_Rect()`.

In other words it seems to me that you need to add .Get_Rect() to actually get the rectangle.

If this doesn't work, please provide code of your `Gate_Class` and the error message you are getting.